# How to disable Agroal in quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

No matter what I try, the application logs like this:

installed features: [agroal, cdi, ...]

I don't want to use agroal and I don't want it present in the runtime at all. I am trying to solve both the proper way to remove the dependency and the feature in quarkus.

Comment: Please [edit] the post and how your `pom.xml` / `build.gradle`. In case you do not have agroal explicitly as dependency: posting the output of `./mvnw dependency:tree` / `./gradlew dependencies` to show the dependency tree might also be helpful. --- I am not sure whether removing/disabling agroal is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Agroal is the implementation of the JDBC connection pool in Quarkus: if you add any JDBC driver or need any (blocking) Datasource, you'll need the Agroal extension.

Agroal was created, and is maintained by, the Middleware Performance team of Red Hat - which is the same team that's making sure that Quarkus is both very light and very high performant, so they work in close collaboration with the Quarkus and Hibernate engineering teams to make sure that Agroal integrates well AND provides amazing performance.

Its design was insipired by HikariCP and should perform similarly, if not better as it has the advantage of being developer after it; the team initially considered to use Hikari instead but it was found to lack capabilities in the area of advanced transaction management, hence a fresh implementation.

There shouldn't be a practical need for disabling it other than you possibly not needing any JDBC connection at all (in which case it should be straight forward to remove); runtime overhead is designed to be minimal, perhaps if you have specific concerns try to narrow it down, elaborate what the problem is or tune it for your own needs.

It's possible that the default settings go "overboard" for your minimal needs: we provide reasonable defaults aiming at high runtime performance out of the box; if you have minimalistic needs try reducing the default size of the pool, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t disable agroal when you include any sql related library (jdbc, hibernate, etc).

It’s the preferred connectionpool. And if I’m not wrong it’s build & maintained in-house by the Hibernate team.